# Aborted git commit during a rebase -- staged changes are lost

Tags: git

I was doing a `git rebase master` on one of my feature branches, and some merge conflicts came up. I resolved them, staged my changes (`git add`) and then mistakenly ran `git commit --amend` instead of `git rebase --continue`. When the editor for the commit message popped up I realized my mistake and removed the commit message to abort the commit. The commit was indeed aborted, but, it seems that this also discarded all my staged changes (i.e. the resolved merge conflicts): `git status` now says `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

Is there a way to get my changes back? Since no commit was involved the reflog doesn't seem to contain anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did a `git stash` before my `git commit --amend`, and that stashed my staged-but-not-committed changes. Hence a `git stash pop` got my make changes back.

Comment: I recommend avoiding `git stash`. This particular accident wasn't too painful to recover from, but as you've now seen, it can be tricky. :-)